# Sent push notification to user at specific time and under certain conditions

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification

on parse I have **Users** and **Events**. Events has a **date** attribute that tells when will the event begin.

Users can attend to a scheduled event. What I want to do is that if user has some event next day the app should notify him at 7pm on a day before the event happens. If user dont have any event scheduled for next day then he shouldnt be notifyied.

What is the most efficient way to do this with parse? What I think it'll work is to create a function on parse Cloud that runs once a day and fetch all the events that are scheduled for the next day and send them scheduled push. The only problem I see is that querying Events is probably limit to 1000 (in case there will be more than 1000 events scheduled for one day) and if scheduled push from Cloud code takes into account time localization. What'll be your approach to do that.

Also I need to tell, that all the events have an array of users that will attend the Event so sending a push to them isnt hard to do it and this code is already done and it works.

Comment: use cloud code of parse

Comment: yeah I would but when I use cloud code and query the Events that I need, and then run a for loop it hard to send push notifications inside for loop because it returns an error that response function should be called just once. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: And also cloud code has some issues with time zones for scheduled notifications.